# How to call UDF which is using spark sql and call that udf in select query

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, azure-databricks

I am new to python programming. Can anyone please help me on below.

I have a UDF as below:

```
def age(dat):
    try:
        df_min_date = spark.sql(f"""SELECT MIN(opdate) dat1
                      FROM ABC
                      WHERE optype='MOVE'
                      AND opdate<={dat}""").first()[0]
       
        df_min_date=datetime(df_min_date.year,df_min_date.month,df_min_date.day)
        l_dat=datetime.strptime(dat,'%Y-%m-%d').date()
        l_dat=datetime(l_dat.year,l_dat.month,l_dat.day)

        age=(df_min_date-l_dat).days
        if age =='':
          age=0
        return age
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"Error: {ex}")
        return 0

f_age = spark.udf.register("f_age",age)
```

I am geting could not serialize object error

I need to use that funtion in spark sql as below

```
spark.sql("""select year,mn, age(dat) age from age""")
```

How can I call this function in my sql query??

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the point of your UDF? It's not using the input argument `dat` at all

Comment: also please provide more details on your tables `age`, `ABC` and `dat`

Comment: @mck Edited the code. Hope you understand what I need. Thanks for your help

Comment: @pythonCoder
Why do you need a udf for this ?  i think you are trying to get the minimum difference between `dat` and smallest `opDate` where `optype = MOVE`   in days , the following sql can accomplish that . 

`spark.sql("SELECT  year , mn , MIN(case when optype='MOVE' and opdate<=dat  then opdate-dat else null end ) MIN_OP_DATE_AGE
from  ABC group by year , mn ")`